# How to calculate percentage by count of column values

Tags: mysql, sql

Given table like this.

```
+----+-------+-----+
| id | class | tag |
+----+-------+-----+
|  1 |     1 | aaa |
|  2 |     1 | abb |
|  3 |     1 | acc |
|  4 |     1 | baa |
|  5 |     2 | bbb |
|  6 |     2 | aaa |
+----+-------+-----+
```

How can I calculate count of tags starts with `a` within the same class for every class in the table? The result of above table will be:

```
+-------+---------+
| class | percent |
+-------+---------+
|     1 |  0.7500 |
|     2 |  0.5000 |
+-------+---------+
```

PS: I've already had a solution, but the table is big(several millions of rows), could you optimize this?

```sql
SELECT class, (CAST(cnt_1 AS DECIMAL) / cnt_2) AS percent 
FROM (
  SELECT class, count(tag) AS cnt_1 FROM (
    SELECT class, tag FROM t_test 
    WHERE tag LIKE 'a%'
  ) AS tmp1 
  GROUP BY class
) AS tmp2 
NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT class, count(tag) AS cnt_2 
  FROM t_test GROUP BY class
) AS tmp3;
```

Comment: You have written the script in right way I feel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use conditional aggregation:

```
select class, avg( tag like 'a%' ) as a_ratio
from t_test
group by class;
```

Percents generally go from 0 to 100.  `ratio` is a better name for your column.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=466ddcb054aeafd2ce55f79271324f9e) is a db<>fiddle illustrating that this works.

Comment: In this case I want to calculate tag% in each class seperately, your result would be 2/3 for class 1, and 1/3 for class 2, which is not correct.

Comment: @KKuroky . . . I cannot fathom where you would get that idea -- and I can't follow your logic.  This works, and I've included a db<>fiddle to illustrate that.

Comment: One more question... How is this possible? Mysql manual for avg function only states that rows of intergers can be passed to the `avg()` function.

Comment: @KKuroky . . . Boolean expressions are treated as integers in a numeric context, with "1" for true and "0" for false.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** Accidentally, very similar to Gordon's answer. I am just adding an edit to make 'percent' look like percentages

```
select class, round((avg(tag like 'a%')*100),2) percent
from t_test
group by class;
```

Comment: I'm not seeing a difference between this and Gordon's earlier answer.

Comment: @P.Salmon Gordon's earlier answer was temporarily deleted when I started my answer. We ended posting the same solution. I'll delete/update mine in a few